# How to wait until a collection is created

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to wait until is collection is created in my database on server startup to perform some operation

I am using the below function to check the same.However it doesn't work.Can you please guide me to make it work

```
module.exports.getNext = function (field, model) {
    var collectionExists = false
    while (!collectionExists) { 
        mongoose.model(collection, identityCounterSchema).find({ 'field': field, 'model': model }, { "count": 1, "_id": 0 }, function (err, result) {
            if (typeof result[0] != 'undefined') collectionExists = true
            console.log("collectionExists " + collectionExists)
        });
}
    mongoose.model(collection, identityCounterSchema).find({ 'field': field, 'model': model }, { "count": 1, "_id": 0 }, function (err, result) {        
        if (err) return 10000
        if (typeof result[0] == 'undefined') return 10000 //first time serverstartup identitycounter schema will not b there
        return (result[0].count + 1);
    });
}
```

Comment: What do you think you mean by *"Wait until created?"* Because unless you are using something like ["Document Validation"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document-validation/) on the server itself, and in fact that actually uses [`.createCollection()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Db.html#createCollection) which does have a callback or promise, then it really should not matter. MongoDB just creates collections/databases when something is "written" to the namespace. So I don't think you completely grasp how this actually works.

Comment: I am using Mongoose_auto_increment plugin to auto increment a field value.This plugin creates a collection called identitycounters automatically on server startup.With the above function i want wait until identitycollection is created

Comment: Again, the collection will be "created" when something is actually "inserted". There is absolutely no need to "wait" or "block" until that is actually done. Mongoose in fact actually does any "waiting" ( such as "Is a connection active?" ) for you. Nothing for you to need to touch here.